# Rails polymorphic comments associate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Trying to work out an polymorphic association where Comments can belong to, for example, Photos and Users. Where a Comment on a user is treated as a "direct message". But I'm getting the User association a bit messed up.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, as: :commentable
end
```

This is incorrect. Ideally, `user.comments` should retrieve all Comment records where `user_id == user.id` and something like `user.messages` should retrieve all Comments where the type is `User` and they are the subject.

Comment: In your User model...you have `has_many :messages`...do you have a Message model?...in other words, saying that this is incorrect may not provide enough information to answer the question.

Comment: @MarkMerritt no I do not have a Message model. I guess my intent there was to create a relation name of "messages" which points to Comments. Does that make sense?

Comment: Got it...I added an answer...try researching the link I provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, as: :commentable, class_name: 'Comment'
end
```

Schema:

```
# Comments
 ...
 t.integer :user_id
 t.integer :commentable_id
 t.string :commentable_type
 ...
```

Then you can invoke:

```
@user.comments # Get all comments created by particular user
@user.messages # Get all comments where particular user is a subject
```

Comment: Yes, this looks exactly like what I had in mind, I'll try that out asap. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was just that `class_name: 'Comment'` I was missing. Everything seems to be working correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

have you added the foreign key and type columns to the `comments` table? within a migration file:

```
  def change
    add_column :comments, :commentable_type, :integer
    add_column, :commentable_type, :string
    add_index :comments, [:commentable_type, :commentable_id]
  end
```

Also make sure you have a `Message` model and it has the associations

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Comment: Yes I have. The issue is that when I called `user.messages` i get `NameError: uninitialized constant User::Message`.

Comment: what does your `Message` model look like?

Comment: Yea, i think that's what's confusing here, I don't have one and i was going about that the wrong way. my intent was to create a relation to Comments called "Messages".

Comment: Yes, you need to create a `Message` model then, I will update my answer